# Generate multisig address

Tags: bitcoin

I am learning blockcypher api. With this request I can simply get new address

```
curl -X POST https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/btc/test3/addrs
```

As a result I get a pair of public and private key

```
"private": "81ee75559d37cbe4b7cbbfb9931ab1ba32172c5cdfc3ac2d020259b4c1104198",
"public": "0231ff9ec76820cb36b69061f6ffb125db3793b4aced468a1261b0680e1ef4883a",
"address": "mvpW7fMSi1nbZhJJDySNS2PUau8ppnu4kY"
```

When I am trying to generate multisig address

```
curl -d '{"pubkeys": ["02c716d071a76cbf0d29c29cacfec76e0ef8116b37389fb7a3e76d6d32cf59f4d3", "033ef4d5165637d99b673bcdbb7ead359cee6afd7aaf78d3da9d2392ee4102c8ea", "022b8934cc41e76cb4286b9f3ed57e2d27798395b04dd23711981a77dc216df8ca"], "script_type": "multisig-2-of-3"}' https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/btc/main/addrs
```

It says that I should add several public keys to make it multisig
The question is: How can I get SEVERAL public keys, if I am getting only ONE public key when generating and address?

Answer (score 0):

The API may have been broken at the time that you originally tried, but the command you posted is correct.

```
curl -d '{"pubkeys": ["02c716d071a76cbf0d29c29cacfec76e0ef8116b37389fb7a3e76d6d32cf59f4d3", "033ef4d5165637d99b673bcdbb7ead359cee6afd7aaf78d3da9d2392ee4102c8ea", "022b8934cc41e76cb4286b9f3ed57e2d27798395b04dd23711981a77dc216df8ca"], "script_type": "multisig-2-of-3"}' https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/btc/main/addr
```

I get the following response to the above curl:

```
{
  "private": "",
  "public": "",
  "address": "3BF1M1PnTge94QewuWh3B8mRVw8U4SVnb4",
  "wif": "",
  "pubkeys": [
    "02c716d071a76cbf0d29c29cacfec76e0ef8116b37389fb7a3e76d6d32cf59f4d3",
    "033ef4d5165637d99b673bcdbb7ead359cee6afd7aaf78d3da9d2392ee4102c8ea",
    "022b8934cc41e76cb4286b9f3ed57e2d27798395b04dd23711981a77dc216df8ca"
  ],
  "script_type": "multisig-2-of-3"
```

This also agrees with the expected response given by the [BlockCypher Developer API](http://dev.blockcypher.com/#generate-multisig-address-endpoint).

If you are still getting an error in response, please edit your post with the exact error you receive.